# In which cases getApplicationContext() function is used

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am following some tutorials for learning android but the problem is they do not contain all the details.

Specifically, it would be great if some light could be shed upon the use cases for `getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of  a `Context` as a handle to your application's resources (i.e. everything in the `res` folder) and to the Android runtime. Classes like `Activity`, `Service`, `Application` inherit from `Context`, among others.

Typically, you'll pass in the current `Activity` whenever a `Context` is required, since Activity inherits from Context.

You'll also find information about using `getApplicationContext()` instead of your activities when a `Context` is required. This usually is to prevent whatever code that needs the Context from unnecessarily holding a reference to your Activity, which in the worst case might preventing it from being garbage collected (passing in the `Application` isn't really a huge problem in that scenario, because it's expected to be around for a long time).

However, there are certain scenarios where an argument of a method is of type `Context`, but an `Activity` is actually required. Using `startActivity()` is one example of this I believe (correct me if I'm wrong).